# Subtrack fields from duplicate lines

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have file with two columns. First column is string, second is positive number. in If first field (string) doesn't have double in file (so, first field is unique for the file), I want to copy that unique line to (let's say) result.txt. If first field does have duplicate in file, then I want to subtract second field (number) in those duplicated lines. By the way, file will have one duplicate max, no more than that. I want to save that also in result.txt. So, output file will have all lines with unique values of first field and lines in which first field is duplicated name and second is subtracted value from those duplicates. Files are not sorted. Here is example:

INPUT FILE:

```
hello 7
something 8    
hey 9    
hello 8    
something 12    
nathanforyou 23
```

OUTPUT FILE that I need (result.txt):

```
hello 1    
something 4    
hey 9    
nathanforyou 23
```

I can't have negative numbers in ending file, so I have to subtract smaller number from bigger. What have I tried so far? All kinds of sort (I figure out how to find non-duplicate lines and put them in separate file, but choked on duplicate substraction), arrays in awk (I saved all lines in array, and do "for" clause... problem is that I don't know how to get second field from array element that is line) etc. By the way, problem is more complicated than I described (I have four fields, first two are the same and so on), but at the end - it comes to this.

Comment: It is a good practice to post your mentioned research-efforts along with the question!

Comment: Hint: You can use HashMap or Dictionary (depeneding on your selected language). Anyways, you should try it first and ask your problems here.

Comment: I just noticed your `By the way, problem is more complicated than I described....` at the end of your question. Don't do that. Either delete that statement if you're confident you can massage any answer you get yourself or edit your question to show your real problem. Do not post an example that doesn't represent your real data and then wait until after you get an answer to pull a "how do I change that to handle my real problem?" as that's immensely annoying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ cat tst.awk
{ val[$1,++cnt[$1]] = $2 }
END {
    for (name in cnt) {
        if ( cnt[name] == 1 ) {
            print name, val[name,1]
        }
        else {
            val1 = val[name,1]
            val2 = val[name,2]
            print name, (val1 > val2 ? val1 - val2 : val2 - val1)
        }
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
hey 9
hello 1
nathanforyou 23
something 4
```

Comment: As ever +1 for making it simple!, tried one myself `awk '{a[$1] -= $2} END{for (i in a) print i, (a[i] < 0 ? -a[i] : a[i])}' file`, for the first computation it does a subtraction of `0 - <actual value>` which screws up the result!

Comment: Yeah you'd need to start with something like `a[$1] = ($1 in a ? a[$1] - $2 : $2)`.

Comment: Really appreciated your suggestion! :)

Comment: Thank you for this beautiful answer Ed. I saw it when you posted it, but I needed some time to understand it (not very familiar with awk). Great solution, my approach was completely wrong. Also, sorry for that annoying part in question, but this is my first post here, obviously I could (and should) write it better. Thanks the others for input, I hope to help somebody else with something the same way you all helped me. All the best!